# Plotting real-time/dynamic data with D3 js

Tags: dynamic, d3.js, real-time

I am completely new to D3 js, but I have exposure to Highcharts. I was able to plot real time/dynamic data using HighCharts and also see the old data as there was a scrollbar feature to scroll left/right on the x-axis. The chart in question was a time-series chart with dynamic values displayed as a bar/line graph.

Is there a way to plot a dynamic chart in D3 which updates every second or so. Also I would like to see old data using panning feature in D3 js as it doesnt support scrollbar.

If you are aware of other open source and non-commercial charts which meet my requirement,kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use C3,js - the pubnub folks have written an extension for (EON) it that readily handles dynamic data; see an overview at https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-02-26-building-realtime-live-updating-animated-graphs-c3-js/ and the code at https://github.com/pubnub/eon-chart